# code for xml feed not working correctly

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to print an xml feed into my php page,but this code is not working correctly, and i have no idea why. It just shows the code as it is on the browser from xpath to ?> . Can anyone help me with this please

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>XML FEED</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <ul>
   <?php
     $dom = simplexml_load_file("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml");
     foreach ($dom->xpath("/channel/item") as $item)
     {
        print "<li>";
        print $item->title;
        print "</li>";
     }
    ?>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For starters, try the full PHP tag   `<?php`

Comment: i did, it still doesnot show anything from the RSS feed

Comment: Hrm.. try adding  print_r($dom);  before your foreach, let's see if you are getting anything.

Comment: yes, i am getting it all, if i add print_r($dom);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adjusting your XPath with double forward slashes as *channel* is not the root element:

```
foreach ($dom->xpath("//channel/item") as $item) {
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, use the root, *rss*, element in expression:

```
foreach ($dom->xpath("/rss/channel/item") as $item) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your server is not configured to allow the short PHP tags (which is discouraged anyway) so Always use the full opening tag.

Since PHP is not parsing your code, the browse gets sent the following...

```
 <? . . . . . foreach ($dom->
```

Which is not valid HTML, so it is not displayed, but if you view the source of your page, you will see more of your PHP code.

Simply starting your code with `<?php` will trigger PHP parsing, and things should work.

Comment: i have used <?php too, it still doesnot show anything from the RSS feed